# how to scan barcode using phonegap

Tags: android, iphone, cordova, barcode-scanner

I need to scan a barcode using phonegap in Android and iPhone.
Is there a way to do this?

Comment: did you get solution to this ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[This link](http://www.mobiledevelopersolutions.com/home/start/twominutetutorials/tmt3) leads you to a page where you can learn how to implement the PhoneGap Barcode Scanner plugin in your application

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, we would like you to include the essential parts of the linked article in your answer, and provide the [link for reference](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259). Failing to do that leaves the answer at risk from link rot.

Comment: It looks to be specifically for Android though. Is there an equivalent for Windows Phone?

Answer (score 47):

Kris Erickson is correct, the Zxing & Phonegap projects has already taken care of the heavy lifting for you.  (My current SO reputation disallows me from commenting, but I would have.)

I've just made an Phonegap/Android app that scans a QR barcode using the plugin [here](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/).  Follow the instructions and you should be successful.    It's possible that the plugin has been written since Kris's answer.

The Javascript is simple, taken straight from https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/

```
    var scanBarcode = function() {
    window.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan( BarcodeScanner.Type.QR_CODE,function(result) {
        alert("We got a barcode: " + result);
    }, function(error) {
        alert("Scanning failed: " + error);
    }, {yesString: "Install"}
    );
 }
```

Comment: does anybody know the password for the zip? I cant unzip the package, it requires a password.

Comment: Dear Rob,
I have some confused. In my opinion, In Barcode Reader, we don't use PhoneGAP. We connect directly with Camera ANdroid or Iphone
PhongeGap use Browse (HTML or Javascript) to call Apps. But no where to use Browse. Thanks you

Comment: Hello @maydenec, I don't think I understand the comment/question.  Sounds like you are not using PhoneGap.  Is that true?  Can you edit?

Comment: In case you want to go straight to the plugin: https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iOS/BarcodeScanner

Answer (score 10):

Your going to have a build a Phonegap [plug-in](http://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins), but the hard work has already be done for  you by [zxing](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/).

Comment: Hi Can you please give pointers as to how to use ZXing implementation in application. I am unable to make the use the same in my application.

Answer (score 1):

I recently used the ZBar plugin + the PhoneGap plugin to access ZBar. More details here - http://blog.infoentropy.com/Use_ZBar_barcode_reader_with_PhoneGap.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/BarcodeScanner
here is some useful example that help to do your solution
https://build.phonegap.com/plugins/13