# Zxing for iphone using HTML5/javascript

Tags: iphone, html, zxing

i am new to ios development .

can anybody pls tell me . is it possible to use Zxing lib for scanning bar/qr-code on iPhone for a webapp(HTML5/javascript) ?

i mean my webapp needs to use Zxing , Is it possible ?

Comment: Let me know if the anwser helped you at all?

Answer (score 3):

Barcode scanning requires use of the camera on your phone, this device is not available from a webapp and therefore you cannot scan barcodes from the webapp, regardless of the library you would like to use.

Also, I dont think you can use C, C++, Objective C libraries from your javascript/html5 these libs would have to be on the phone where your code cannot get to it, and your browser most certainly cant run it.

One alternative would be PhoneGap, I am not too familiar with it, but it is an iOS (and or Android) shell around a webapp that runs as a native app. You could probably get camera support in there and maybe use the Zxing lib. You would have to look into that, but then you dont 'really'  have a webapp anymore either.

EDIT: For phoneGap and Zxing see also:  [how to scan barcode using phonegap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3888396/how-to-scan-barcode-using-phonegap)

Answer (score 2):

These days you can get it working with the HTML5 Camera API and this little beauty; https://github.com/LazarSoft

enjoy.