# iPhone phone gap barcode scanner using Xcode

Tags: iphone, xcode, cordova

i'm developing an iPhone phone gap barcode scanner application using html5.

i have followed the below link:

https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iPhone/BarcodeScanner

After build this project i am not getting any errors. but at the same time no output.

here is my code.

```
function scanQRCode()
{
 navigator.notification.alert('Scan click');
 window.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan( BarcodeScanner.Type.QR_CODE,
                                           function(result) {
                                           if (result.cancelled)
                                           navigator.notification.alert("the user cancelled the scan")
                                           else
                                           navigator.notification.alert("we got a barcode: " + result.text)
                                           },
                                           function(error) {
                                           navigator.notification.alert("scanning failed: " + error)
                                           }
                                           );

navigator.notification.alert('After Scan click');
}
```

still getting the first alert only not the bottom one. its confirms me there is problem with scan function call. but i have imported everything as like the above link that i mentioned.

its not opening the camera.

Please assist me, to fix that issue.

my whole idea is to read a QR Code in **iPhone** not in android.

Note:
i have two warnings
1) No previous prototype for 'unsigned int zxing::logDigits_15(unsigned int)'
2) file://localhost/Users/malaris/Documents/Projects/MyFirstTest/MyFirstTest/zxing-all-in-one.cpp: warning: Semantic Issue: No previous prototype for function 'logDigits_15'

Thanks in advance,
Karthick

Comment: see the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3888396/how-to-scan-barcode-using-phonegap

Comment: or see the link http://www.cybersprocket.com/phonegap-barcodes-ios/

Comment: did you add plugin name to plugin list of phonegap ?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your links and go through it. still facing the same problem.